# How can the generic type be inferred to refer to the this of the array

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

How can the generic type be inferred to refer to the `this` of the array in the following:

```js
type FN<T extends unknown[]> = (...args: T)=>number
type InferFN<T> = T extends (...args: infer A)=>number ? FN<A> : never

type FNArray<T extends readonly any[]> = T extends readonly [...FNs: infer P ] ? {
  [I in keyof P] : InferFN<P[I]>
} : unknown

// the type of fnArray should be FNArray<typeof fnArray>
const fnArray = [
  (value: number)=>value,
  (text: string)=>text, // should fail typechecking
] as const

// How can the type of fnArray be made to equal `ActualFnArrayType` below
// i.e `const fnArray : ActualFnArrayType = [....] or
// `const fnArray : FNArray<this> = [....]
// so that fnArray is type checked?
type ActualFnArrayType = FNArray<typeof fnArray>
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=49&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgcgHgCpQgD2BAdgEwM5QCuWA1lgPYDuWA2gLoB8UAvFABQB0XAhgE4DmeAFxQkASmYMshALYAjCLwBQoSFACSWAGaL4yJqxTpMuApx4DhUAJbbFUAIISpshbygB+WIgdMRWCAA3RSUVcGh4B15ebhBkVAxsfCheCG4cciwAGxAobiwQegNRBJNk1PTMnKgaLg54K1sddwAFKDpPKABvJSga9RssKBIIEHItKBaOkU1mvRaadUYlAF8oEWIyKixQgHpdqGAAC2hVaHGoLSwomNy8I-JCLJwoBW8b2IQzi6uPkAYlABjTJ4YCXa7RWIsGq9diBbhZQgQfyuRTOeGIiAAGlhbEwGBEoN4tn4znxwCxUH2UHuj2el241iyh3CgJOgJIJKUHW4BGBWFBewOAAkqFBAflDicWWofhDbq9oDJ0qdyKgAI6EBFQAAGDkBwC1WRg8tiSHCOsVWSoSmp1g40B1-NB4L+60cBqNJr+5rUrFqdQ65GU1KdILBv0huREkSjXyO1jwxQDXDotoOeDVx24EdNuUTMugbIgHIgOA8YTU+sNCO9Ud90FYsduX3Ccr+AKAA)

Comment: Could you please elaborate why `(text: string)=>text` should fail? Also, it is not clear for me what you want to achieve.

Comment: @captain-yossarian it should fail cause FN's type is `=>number` and not `=>string`.  I want to assign type ActualFnArrayType to fnArray and have it type checked.  Hover of ActualFnArrayType to see why it should fail.